# Difference between 生气 and 愤怒

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

I can't find the difference between 生气 and 愤怒.

Oxford Dictionary says *angry* means 生气, but I found 愤怒 in the online dictionary. Both have more than 20 million hits on Google, both have pictures of angry people, and nowhere am I able to find if they have a different meaning or if using one or the other is preferred.

Comment: A good place to look for sentences with these words is, for example, http://dj.iciba.com/%E6%84%A4%E6%80%92-1.html Often, the English is appalling, but I presume the Chinese is good. Then you can see how the words are used in actual sentences, and maybe spot the differences yourself.

Comment: 生气 angry   愤怒 furious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of degree of anger, `憤怒` is higher `生气`.

In terms of context, `生气` is usually used in colloquial context, whereas `憤怒` is usually used in formal context.

Another term you may be interested in is `抓狂`, which is a colloquial term with degree of anger higher than `憤怒`

[Here](http://kids.yam.com/joke/article.php?cid=general&id=170025) is an interesting joke that can hopefully help you understand better.
I have quoted below the key phrases that denote the difference (forgive the offensive language used):

**生气**

> 「X的，神經病。你去死好了！」
>
> "F***ing psycho, go to hell!"

**憤怒**

> 「你欠扁是不是？妈的，要是再打来，给我试试看！」
>
> "You want some beef? F***, I dare you call again!"

**抓狂**

> 「他妈的！去你老母！你娘卡好！」
>
> "F*** your mom!" (three variations with the same meaning)

Comment: It should be noted that 生气 and 抓狂 are both less formal to 愤怒.

Answer (score 2):

The first, 生气，would mean angry in the colloquial sense. 愤怒 is a little more strong, and is not usually used in normal speech. You would say, 我生气了. 愤怒鸟 however, means Angry Birds in Chinese.

Comment: hello， thank you, do you mean   愤怒 is usually not used in normal speech because "it is not used in spoken chinese a lot" or because the word is more extreme and only used when someone is really really angry so it has less use cases?

Comment: @Nannakina Yes, you are correct. 愤怒 is stronger. Think of it this way: 愤怒=wrath. 生气=anger.

Answer (score 0):

生气is slightly 愤怒, 愤怒is seriously 生气

Answer (score 0):

They are different disagree in expressing "angry". 生气 means someone is angry, but it is not 愤怒。愤怒 means someone that is very angry.

Answer (score 0):

生气和愤怒是同义词，生气更常用一些。口语使用比较用的多一些。生气可以是轻的，也可以是严重的情绪表达。但愤怒通常是是程度重一些。